# ES6 Class implementing typescript interface becoming WET

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a class that implements an interface and has a constructor method, but that is driving me to repeat a lot of code.

Here an example:

```
export interface IComputer {
  id: number;
  model: string;
  color: string;
  screenSize: number;
  language: string;
  usbPorts: number;
  ramGb: number;
  brand: string;
  year: number;
}

class Computer implements IComputer {
  id: number;
  model: string;
  color: string;
  screenSize: number;
  language: string;
  usbPorts: number;
  ramGb: number;
  brand: string;
  year: number;

  constructor(computer: IComputer) {
    this.id = computer.id;
    this.model = computer.model;
    this.color = computer.color;
    this.screenSize = computer.screenSize;
    this.language = computer.language;
    this.usbPorts = computer.usbPorts;
    this.ramGb = computer.ramGb;
    this.brand = computer.brand;
    this.year = computer.year;
  }
}
```

I believe that is not the best naming each property three times to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: `constructor(computer: IComputer) { Object.assign(this, computer); }`

Comment: Cool, thanks! And how would you do for not repeating it in the properties of the class?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's unavoidable. But I could be wrong.

Comment: It depends on particular case. In the example above a class is not needed at all, having it as plain object would be enough. Notice that `Object.assign` will copy all props that don't exist in IComputer too, that's why we pick props by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DRYer type-safe version is:

```
class Computer implements IComputer {
  id: number = this.computer.id;
  model: string = this.computer.model;
  ...

  constructor(private computer: IComputer) {}
}
```

It is possible to skip enumeration of class properties in class, in order to do that an interface should become abstract class and be inherited. Then properties should be enumerated in class constructor to be picked from `computer` parameter:

```
export abstract class IComputer {
  id: number;
  model: string;
  ...
}

class Computer extends IComputer {
  constructor(computer: IComputer) {
    super();
    const keys = Object.keys(computer).filter(key => ['id', 'model', ...].includes(key));
    for (const key of keys) {
      this[key] = computer[key];
    }
}
```

In this case it cannot be guaranteed that a set of picked properties will match interface properties.